# Router Outlet not rendered in unit test

Tags: angular

Note: I am quite new to Angular programming!

I try to write unit tests for routing.

The `AppComponent` renders `MasterLayoutComponent` in its single unnamed router outlet.

`MasterLayoutComponent` contains two named router outlets:

```
<kui-toolbar (contextmenu)="isDevMode">
    <router-outlet name="toolbar"></router-outlet>
</kui-toolbar>
<div class="content" (contextmenu)="isDevMode">
    <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is the template of the `AppListComponent` that should render to the 'main' router outlet:

```
<p>app-list works!</p>
```

This is my route definition:

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [

  { path: "",   redirectTo: "appList", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "appList", pathMatch: "full" },

  { path: "appList", component: MasterLayoutComponent, children: [{ path: "", component: AppListComponent, outlet: "main" }] }
];
```

This is my test code:

```
describe("App Routing", () => {

  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MasterLayoutComponent>;
  let masterLayoutComponent: MasterLayoutComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(appRoutes),
        NgxsModule.forRoot(),
        KuiCommonModule,
        KuiBaseComponentsModule,
        LocalizationModule,
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        AppConfigurationService,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppListComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MasterLayoutComponent);
    masterLayoutComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

    router.initialNavigation();
  });


  it("should navigate to '' on path \"\"", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Trigger the router to navigate to path ""
    router.navigate([""]);
    // Wait for the router to do its work
    tick();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(location.path()).toBe("");
  }));
});
```

The test succeeds.

When I break on the expectation and look at the value of `fixture.nativeElement.innerHTML` I can see the following result:

```
<kui-toolbar _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
   <kui-breadcrumb _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-navigation-items="[object Object]">
      <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="wrapper">
         <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="links">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
               }-->
            <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="link">
               <button _ngcontent-c2="" disabled="" title="Home">
                  <!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                     }-->
                  <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="icon" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;assets/svg/Icon.Home.svg&quot;);"></div>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </kui-breadcrumb>
   <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="additional-content">
      <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0="" name="toolbar"></router-outlet>
   </div>
</kui-toolbar>
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="content">
   <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0="" name="main"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The 'main' router outlet is not replaced by the expected HTML of the `AppListComponent`.

What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try adding `MasterLayoutComponent` to your declarations array in your test spec and check?

Comment: @AmitChigadani - It's already declared by `KuiCommonModule`

Comment: Well then `RouterTestingModule` probably does spy on the routes, which will actually not navigate to the url but assures that it would have navigated to it. What you could do is `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['your-path'])`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) probably does spy on the routes, which will actually not navigate to the url but assures that it would have navigated to it. Hence the component `AppListComponent` is not rendered.

This is fine for unit testing because you only concentrate on testing the parent component (`MasterLayoutComponent`).

Instead you could verify the router navigation as follows

```
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['new-path'])
```